# Задать формат строке

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc, format

Друзья, есть в модели `public string Variable { get; set; }`.

Во view она выводится в цикле таким образом: `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Variable)`,  и мы получаем на странице данные в виде "9999999". Стоит задача вывести в виде "9 999 999".

Пробовал примерно следующие варианты:

```
@String.Format("{00:000,00}", m.Variable)
```

Ничего не изменяется в принципе.

```
@Html.FormatValue(m.Variable, "{0:00,00}")
```

Аналогично предыдущей ситуации, но

```
@String.Format("{00:000,00}", 9999999)
```

В свою очередь выводит нужный результат:

> "9 999 999"

Другие форматы вызывают ошибку при компиляции. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? Проблема в формате? Или не подходят данные инструменты для этой задачи? 
Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Я не сильно осведомлен в этом вопросе. Думаю, можно попробовать поменять настройки локализации и форматирования глобально в web.config

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте NumberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator(v=vs.110).aspx

другие примеры форматирования:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx